# Running an ANOSIM with specific data in R?

Tags: r, vegan

I've tried to complete an ANOSIM with data on a study I have carried out but I get multiple errors and i'm not sure how to fix it. Most of the errors are "dissimilarities have 24 observations, but grouping has 23". I'm trying to see the similarity in community structure between multiple samples.
my code so far is

```
setwd()
#load invertebrate data

Invertebrates<- read.csv(file="Invertebrates.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")

#install packages

install.packages("vegan")
library(vegan)

#make community matrix

com<-Invertebrates[,2:ncol(Invertebrates)]
m_com<-as.matrix(com)

# group by site

group=Invertebrates[,1]

#ANOSIM

invert.ano<-anosim(m_com,group)
```

Then I get

> Error in anosim(m_com, group) : there should be replicates within groups

Thanks for any help

```
Invertebrates <- structure(list(Site = structure(c(10L, 14L, 6L, 3L, 24L, 12L, 7L, 18L, 1L, 8L, 15L, 5L, 16L, 23L, 4L, 11L, 21L, 19L, 9L, 13L
    ), .Label = c("Anax parthenope", "Anisus vortex", "Asellus aquaticus", 
    "Bathyomphalus contortus", "Bithynia leachii", "Bithynia tentaculata", 
    "Coenagrion pulchellum", "Corixa punctata", "Dytiscus marginalis", 
    "Gammarus pulex", "Gyraulus albus", "Haliplus fluviatilis", "Haplotaxis gordioides", 
    "Ilyocoris cimicoides", "Lymnaea stagnalis", "Lymnaea truncatula", 
    "Oxygastra curtisii", "Physa fontilnalis", "Piscicola geometra", 
    "Planorbis cornatus", "Planorbis planorbis", "Radix ovata", "Radix palustris", 
    "Sialis lutaria"), class = "factor"), Finglesham.Brook.A = c(112L, 
    1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Betteshanger.Pond.A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Betteshanger.Pond.B = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Great.Mongeham.A = c(7L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Site.7.SS.A = c(6L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Great.Mongeham.B = c(32L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Broad.dike.A = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Broad.dike.B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), S3.Broad.dike.SS.B = c(14L, 
    0L, 7L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Site.6.NS.B = c(65L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fowlmead.Lake.A = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Site.7.SS.B = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fowlmead.lake.B = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Adelaide.NS.A = c(5L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Little.Downs.Bridge.B = c(48L, 
    8L, 0L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Finglesham.Brook.B = c(78L, 0L, 3L, 15L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L), 
        Adelaide.SS.A = c(8L, 0L, 0L, 33L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 12L, 0L, 4L, 19L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L), Adelaide.SS.B = c(4L, 
        0L, 20L, 9L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 
        0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Ham.Fen.SS = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        Adelaide.NS.B = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Site.6.NS.A = c(58L, 
        0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), S3.Broad.dike.SS.A = c(24L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 
        0L, 0L, 3L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L), Little.Downs.Bridge.A = c(10L, 16L, 23L, 46L, 0L, 
        0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L
        )), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Invertebrates)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Invertebrates, 20))`.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this site. How do I upload the data?

Comment: 1) Run the code line `dput(head(Invertebrates, 20))`; 2) edit the question with its output, like you have edited before, but with the output of that command.

Comment: I think i've done it. :)

Comment: See @broti's answer. When I ran `adonis2(m_com ~ Site, data = Invertebrates)` it gives `No residual component`, there are no residual degrees of freedom. Revise your goals, you don't seem to have enough data for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
table(Invertebrates$Site)
```

you will see that there you're grouping variable is not actually grouping anything. That is, there is maximum one observation per group. But ANOSIM requires the data to be grouped.

If I just make up a random grouping variable, like this:

```
Invertebrates$Group <- sample(c(1,2), nrow(Invertebrates), replace = TRUE)
```

and rerun your analysis:

```
Invertebrates$Group <- sample(c(1,2), nrow(Invertebrates), replace = TRUE)
group <- Invertebrates[, "Group"]
invert.ano <- anosim(m_com, group)
```

It works!

Comment: So how can I group it?

Comment: Depends on what you want to find out

Comment: I want to know if there is a relationship between salinity and community structure? I tried making Salinity the grouping factor but I get the different observations error again.